# C# Запустить 2 одинаковых события

Tags: c#, рисование

Вот например у меня есть PictureBox и мне надо рендерить на нем что-нибудь и проверять не рисую ли я на том что рендерится, если делать в MouseMove то к-во того что рендерится тормозит сам процес рисования что логично. С логикой событий в C# не знаком. Как мне делать это не теряя скорости?

Answer (score 1):

Когда возникает событие, то происходит последовательный вызов обработчиков, которые подписаны на событие в отдельном потоке.

Иначе говоря, пока не отработает одни обработчик, то второй не запустится.

Получается, что нужно как можно быстрее освобождать обработчики событий.

Можно попробовать создавать отдельный Task в обработчике события и тем самым моментально его покидать.

Comment: У меня идея, делать вычесления в другом потоке пока MouseMove, но как из другого потока получать MouseMove?

Comment: Делегат на событые?